# For ODE x'=f(x/t) if x(t) is a solution, prove that (1/a)x(at) is also a solution for every a \in R

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For ODE x'=f(x/t) if x(t) is a solution, prove that (1/a)x(at) is also a solution for every a in R

How can I prove that?

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE. For others to be able to give better help, it is the custom on this web site that the one who asks the question also provides their own thoughts/ideas/tries on the problem. Could you tell us what you have done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here comes a *hint* (since you are new, next time I'll wait until you provide what you have done):

To make things clearer, write your differential equation as
$$
x'(t)=f(x(t)/t).
$$
Then, let
$$
y(t)=\frac{1}{a}x(at).
$$
Now differentiate and verify that $y$ solves the differential equation, i.e.
$$
y'(t)=f(y(t)/t).
$$

Comment: Thanks for your clarification about questions in general, and for your answer. I was looking for a hint to the next step - once you differentiate you get x'(at)= f(x(at)/at). Is that enough to show that this is a solution, for s=at, since x'(s)=f(x(s)/s)?

Comment: Yes, that suffices.